# Nuxt doesn't accept lang attribute "scss" in layout dir

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, vue-loader

I use sass code in nuxt components simply by adding lang="scss" in the style tags. When I add this attribute to the style tag in a layout file (layouts folder) the style tag isn't processed any more and the following css (scss) code ignored.

Can anybody explain what's happening and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `node-sass` and `sass-loader` in order to use pre-processor, run this terminal command in the project folder

`npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`

And take a look this link to enable other pre-processor in Vue, [Pre-Processors - vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html)

Comment: Thank you Jefry, but node-sass and sass-loader are already installed. In components the lang attribute works fine and I can use scss. It just doesn't work in the nuxt specific layouts (layout folder).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: After having re-started the dev server (npm run dev) nuxt compiled scss code correctly. The issue seems to be limited to the live browser update in dev mode.